# In Python, identify parts of an e-mail address

Tags: python, email

Given a list of e-mail addresses:

```
list = ('First Last <first@example.com>' , 'name@example.org')
```

some of which contain first and last name, others which just contain an e-mail address, how can I loop through the list and extract a first and last name (if they exist), and the email address?

Thanks.

Comment: Names can have multiple words for first name, multiple words for last name, words between the first and last name, words before the first name, words after the last name...

Comment: As in "please write the code for me"?  Or as in "I tried something and it didn't work?"  If you tried something please post what you tried.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe there is a Python library that makes this easy.  Just learned about email.utils, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import email.utils
map(email.utils.parseaddr, email_list)
```

Comment: @ensnare: You should accept the answer. If this is what you are looking for.